# How to create smooth rounded corners on a popup widget in Qt

Tags: windows, qt, qt5, styling, rounded-corners

I have a widget with the `windowsflag` `Qt::Popup` set, and I'm trying to create smooth rounded corners.

I've tried using a stylesheet, but then the transparent part of the corners become black. The same happens if I overwrite the widget's paint event and draw a rectangle with rounded corners in the widget.

I've also tried to set a mask, but the result gets very pixelated.

After some reading, I found out that the black corners appears because the widget is a top-level widget. But I would think that it's still possible somehow?

How can I either get rid of the black corners or to smoothen the mask?

The paint event:

```cpp
void PopUp::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QPainter painter(this);

    QColor greyColor(0xFFC5C6C6);
    QRect rect(0, 0, width(), height());  
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
    painter.setBrush(QBrush(greyColor));
    painter.setPen(QPen(greyColor));
    painter.drawRoundedRect(rect, 10, 10);
}
```

The function that sets the mask:

```cpp
void PopUp::setRoundedCorners(int radius)
{
    QRegion verticalRegion(0, radius, width(), height() - 2 * radius);
    QRegion horizontalRegion(radius, 0, width() - 2 * radius, height());
    QRegion circle(0, 0, 2 * radius, 2 * radius, QRegion::Ellipse);

    QRegion region = verticalRegion.united(horizontalRegion);
    region = region.united(circle);
    region = region.united(circle.translated(width() - 2 * radius, 0));
    region = region.united(circle.translated(width() - 2 * radius, height() - 2 * radius));
    region = region.united(circle.translated(0, height() - 2 * radius));

    setMask(region);
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**1.** Create a widget and set its [windowFlags](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt.html#WindowType-enum) to `Qt::Window | Qt::FramelessWindowHint`, and  its [attribute](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt.html#WidgetAttribute-enum) to `Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground`.

**2.** Create a `QFrame` inside of a widget.

**3.** Set a stylesheet to `QFrame`, for example:

```
border: 1px solid red;
border-radius: 20px;
background-color: black;
```