# Does Windows support Mac-style PopOver controls?

Tags: macos, qt, user-interface, winapi, cross-platform

Mac supports these sort of views:

[image]

https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/macos/windows-and-views/popovers/

They are like short-lived tool panels but automatically disappear when you click outside the view.

I am trying to figure out if we can utilise them from a cross-platform Mac/Win application but can't be sure if WinAPI or Qt supports something like this? Does anyone know what classes they might be?

Comment: I created my own. You may check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24612576/how-to-create-smooth-rounded-corners-on-a-popup-widget-in-qt/24617444#24617444). It is a good start point. You just need to implement necessary modality and shading.

Comment: Sounds kind of like a [Tooltip control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/tooltip-controls).